# Switch treating integer as 'truthy' value

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have an array with strings and numbers as indexes which I iterate over using a 'foreach' loop and a switch statement:-

```
$test = array(1, 2, 3, 'test' => 'value');
foreach ($test as $k => $v)
{
    switch ($k)
    {
        case 'test': 
            echo $v . "\n"; 
            break;
    }
}
```

The output is.

```
1
value
```

Switch seems to handle the string 'test' and the integer 1 as the same, this doesn't seem right.

Comment: put a break in each case statement.

Comment: @vascowhite I found it. But the 0-problem is hidden in a 3-years-old comment and solved in the same way: converting to a string.

Comment: I retracted my close vote, my apologies for not reading the question properly. This is an interesting issue, if I find a good solution I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is because any string, when loosely compared to an integer, is cast to an integer. If the string does not begin with an numeric character, the result of this cast will usually be zero.

```
$test = 'test';
var_dump((int) $test); // int(0)
```

`case` comparisons in a `switch` are loose comparisons, not strict (`==` vs `===`).

Given the above, here's what happens in the loop, because you are switching on the *key* (0-indexed) not the value:

```
0 == 'test'      // true
1 == 'test'      // false
2 == 'test'      // false
'test' == 'test' // true
```

See [string conversion to numbers](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.conversion) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to convert the indexes to strings.

```
switch ($k . '')
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure why this is happening, but I suspect that, as `switch` uses loose comparisons (== rather than ===), it is seeing 0 as 'truthy' and so executing your case.

One workaround is to test that the value passed is a string:-

```
$test = array(1, 2, 3, 'test' => 'value');
foreach ($test as $k => $v)
{
    switch (is_string($k))
    {
        case 'test':
            echo $v . "\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/mu63O).

However, I'm not sure it is any better than your solution, although, to me, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is simple.

Since `switch` performs comparison with normal PHP type-judging, your first array element will pass check since it have `0` key, which is equal to `test` because (int) cast of `'test'` is `0`.

You may assign any value to 0-indexed element and see it in your check. But if you'll do

```
$test = array(1=>1,2=>2, 3=>3, 'test' => 'value');
```

-you'll see only `'value'` passed your check

Answer (score 0):

You need use `break` for avoid this behavior
like this

```
switch ((string)$k)
{
    case 'test':
        echo $v . "\n";
        break;
    default: echo "-\n";
}
```

Comment: This is not the issue, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: It has nothing to do with break;